# Test if all leaf properties in a nested object are true

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way (without writing a recursive function manually) to test if all leaf properties in an object are `true`?

```
obj = { a: true, b: { c: true } }
```

If it was an array, I could `_.flattenDeep(obj).values().every(_.identity)`, but it is an object.

There are only boolean leaf properties in the object.

Comment: btw, `b` is a property too.

Comment: @NinaScholz corrected.

Comment: so, `b` is a property too, that meant there is non true property also you are allowing? so what exactly you don't want to allow? a `false`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can avoid recursion here. If you "flattened" an object it may have two or more properties with the same name.

Comment: For fun: `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf(": false")==-1);`

Comment: @AndyGaskell is there a way to flatten an object? I don't know of any. I could then make sure that all names are unique

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee clarified

Comment: @mplungjan Unless there is a key `": false"` :)

Comment: @mplungjan, exactly that would be my answer also if the `false` is the target, I was waittng for it to confirm, but the case will be different if it will not allow any other primitive value and string

Comment: @AurelBílý if there is, then whoever used that key is an idiot.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee The question now says there are only boolean leaf properties.

Comment: yeah the question has now changed. @mplungjan but if there is an idiot, this solution will not work for that idiot haha. so? what if (we have `: false`) we replace `false` with `""` from that string and there is a parse error then it was a key otherwise not. (obviously it will not be performance efficient, but avoiding a recursive code by us, as OP want)

Comment: Life is too short to make that kind of input checking. Whoever sends you the JSON has to adhere to common sense and some data contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible. If you flatten an object, you'll override duplicate keys which will render the whole operation senseless. A very simple recursive function can check it though

```js
function allTrue(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj)
    .every(v => v instanceof Object ? allTrue(v) : v === true)
}

let obj = {
  a: true,
  b: {
    c: true
  }
};
console.log(allTrue(obj));
```

Comment: Seeing as this is a lodash question, `_.values(obj)` might be better?